# Can we wear hats in chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, winter-bash-2012

I want to wear my hat in chat. Any chance of this happening?

I spend a lot of time in chat, so showing off my achievements in chat would be something that interests me.

HAT GET. :)

Comment: Well, you can't spell chat without hat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hats work on chats now, as of WinterBash 2013.

I assume they will be rolling it out to the network in a while.

[image]

Comment: They *should* be working everywhere, are they not? Also, this is a Winter Bash 2012 question.

Comment: @balpha They are not. I just assumed the old hat questions still counted as feature-requests.

Comment: Ah, it works on chat.SO, but not chat.SE. That's a bug, I'll fix.

Comment: @balpha will it be proper to clone this question and just tag with winterbash2013 instead?

Comment: Whhoo, there is my picture.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Meh, I guess we can leave it as is. Or tag with both and clarify that there were no chat hats in 2012, but there are in 2013.

Comment: @balpha OK, only 3 [tagged both status-completed and tatus-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined+status-completed) but guess it would make sense to make this the fourth. :-)

Comment: Chat.se is fixed now. Note that hats exist only in live chat pages, not in the transcript etc.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I'm going to have to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this. There wasn't a good way of implementing this without certain site functions taking a big hit. Also remember: chat.stackoverflow.com is *the same size* as the *entire* chat.stackexchange.com. Hats are an extra javascript overlay that takes a minute to get going. It was too expensive for us to implement this year.

However: I really like this idea! We will definitely consider it for next year. And, as others have pointed out: being in chat will earn you some hats down the road. :)

Comment: I guess that's as good as I could have hoped for.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm. I was just about to try and userscript this, and then I found your answer... Should I not? Will it bring down the entire SE network? :-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Well. Go for it, and if/when it breaks everything, we'll tell you. We'll *really* tell you. In fact, go post it on Stack Apps!

Comment: lmao@"We'll *really* tell you" :-)

Comment: "We will definitely consider it for next year. And, as others have pointed out: being in chat will earn you some hats down the road." -- Aarthi, 2012