# Hats don't display on per-site metas?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, per-site-meta, winter-bash-2013

It seems I cannot show off my awesome new collection of haberdashery on the Meta-sites associated with my favorite Stack Exchange Sites.

This is an outrage.

<sub>Almost as much of an outrage as [the lack of chat hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159194/can-we-wear-hats-in-chat)</sub>

Comment: It looks like the metas award their own hats.

Comment: @Charles not so! While there are hats *awarded* for participation on meta, hats can only be *displayed* on the main site. It's an outrage!

Comment: I can see my hats earned on meta-stackoverflow on my gravatar, you just need to wear it ? Did I misunderstood ?

Comment: @AYK MSO is the exception here. Try it on any other meta site.