# Are the hats available on per-site metas?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I have voted on a number of posts, both on main sites and on their per-site meta's. This has resulted in the Sufganiyot hat for the main sites, but not for the per-site metas.

From a discussion in the Tavern on the Meta, it seemed that one did not get the secret "Hairboat's revenge" hat for activities on a per-site meta, either.

A [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159401/hats-dont-display-on-per-site-metas) was asked in 2013, but not answered.

So - does this mean that only activity on the main site will earn you hats?

Comment: See the last point in the anwer to the the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems per-site metas are linked to their parent sites. I remember one year you would get a unicorn hat on the main site, for doing something on the associated meta site - if per-site meta sites had their own set of hats, this wouldn't have been possible.

And since code that doesn't need to change usually doesn't change, I'd bet it's still that way.

Meta.SE is different though, and has its hat rack. Nobody really goes to StackExchange.com anyway.

Comment: The existence of the [Airing of Grievances Hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/the-airing-of-grievances) suggests that you are right; as does Balpha's link to the duplicate question.