# Hats don't display in chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we wear hats in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159194/can-we-wear-hats-in-chat)

I have found myself a neat necktie, but it doesn't show up in the chat rooms.

Will the chat rooms be updated to support Winter Bash hats?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Can we wear hats in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159194/169404).

To quote Aarthi:

> Sorry, I'm going to have to status-declined this. There wasn't a good way of implementing this without certain site functions taking a big hit.