# My hat is not showing on the chat room list of occupants

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, winter-bash

There appears to be a bug in the chatroom code - my hat is not showing on the chat room list of occupants:

[image]

It is correctly showing in the message list:

[image]

My question is not a dupe of [Can we wear hats in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159194/can-we-wear-hats-in-chat):

As you can see one avatar has a hat and the other doesn't. They should either both have a hat or neither should have a hat ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the user list isn't very stable and has other animations, it simply doesn't show them there, just on messages and your avatar.